# ¿Cómo obtener cuántos días tiene el mes de una fecha pasada como argumento en una función, en Java?

Tags: java

```
public class CFecha {
    //ATRIBUTOS    
    int Dia;
    int Mes;
    int Año;

    //CONSTRUCTORES

    public CFecha(int pdia, int pmes, int paño){
        Dia=pdia;
        Mes=pmes;
        Año=paño;

    }

    //MODIFICADORES
    public void setDia(int pdia){
        Dia=pdia;
    }
    public void setMes(int pmes){
        Mes=pmes;
    }
    public void setAño(int paño){
        Año=paño;
    }
    //ACCEDENTES
    public int getDia(){
        return Dia;
    }
    public int getMes(){
        return Mes;
    }
    public int getAño(){
        return Año;
    }



    //OTROS MÉTODOS

    public CFecha FechaMayor(CFecha fecha)
    {
    int Dia1=fecha.getDia();
    int Mes1=fecha.getMes();
    int Año1=fecha.getAño();

    if(Año>Año1)    
      return this;


    else
        if(Año<Año1)    
            return fecha;
        else   
        if(Año==Año1)        
        {
            if(Mes>Mes1)     
                return this;        
            else 
                if(Mes<Mes1)
                    return fecha;
                else
                    if(Dia>Dia1)
                        return this;
                    else
                        return fecha;       

        }
    return null;
    }
    public void EscribeFecha(){
        System.out.println("La fecha mayor es: "+Dia +"/"+ Mes+"/"+ Año);
    }

}
```

¿Cómo puedo mostrar cuántos días tiene ese mes (si tengo una fecha en la clase principal, quiero saber cuántos)?

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor es definir un método como el siguiente:

```
public static int getDiasEnMes(int mes, int año) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, año);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mes - 1); // Índice del mes, empezando en 0
    return calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
```

Este método crea un objeto `Calendar` con el `mes` y el `año` especificados y obtiene el último día de ese `mes`, o lo que es lo mismo, el número total de días de ese `mes`.

Fíjate en que para asignar al `mes` se le resta 1 al argumento que recibe la función. Esto es porque para el `calendar`, enero es el mes 0, febrero el 1, marzo el 2...

Echa un vistazo a la documentación:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum(int)

Answer (score 0):

Como no sé exactamente como vas a proporcionar los datos te pongo la solución más completa, coge lo que necesites:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
//Para introducir los datos con una cadena con el formato anterior
Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
//Para introducir los datos con una fecha tipo java.util.Date
c.setTime(convertedDate);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Puedes ver la salida fácil para asegurarte que hace lo que quieres:

```
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(c.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Para mí, la forma más sencilla sería:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(today.lengthOfMonth());
```

Comment: La pregunta dice _¿Cómo obtener cuántos días tiene el mes de una fecha pasada **como argumento en una función?**_ No olvides además leer [answer]. Pulsa en [edit] para corregir tu respuesta.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/376972)

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Porque dices que no resuelve la pregunta?

Comment: Lo haces simplemente para fecha actual