# ¿Cómo puedo calcular en java cuántos días tiene un año o un mes, según la fecha introducida por un usuario?

Tags: java

me gustaría saber como puedo calcular en java cuantos días tiene un mes y cuántos días tiene un año según la fecha que haya introducido un usuario. Hasta ahora en el programa me muestra el día del mes, día de la semana, día del año, nombre del mes, número del mes y el año. Pero no sé que es lo que hay que utilizar para sacar cuantos días tiene un mes y un año determinados. Inserto el código aquí debajo, (Gracias a todos).

```
private static Scanner sc;

    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Introduzca una fecha (yyyy-MM-dd): ");
    String fecha = sc.nextLine();
    
    LocalDate fecha1 = LocalDate.parse(fecha);
    DateTimeFormatter personalizado = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDate fecha1personalizado = LocalDate.parse(fecha,personalizado);
    
    int diaMes = fecha1.getDayOfMonth();
    
    DayOfWeek diaSemana = fecha1.getDayOfWeek();
    int diaAnyo = fecha1.getDayOfYear();
    
    Month nombreMes = fecha1.getMonth();
    
    int numeroMes = fecha1.getMonthValue();
    System.out.printf("La fecha introducida es: %s\n ", fecha1personalizado);
    
    int anyo = fecha1.getYear();
                
    System.out.println("Información sobre la fecha introducida");
    String caracter ="*";
    int count = 39;
    System.out.println(caracter.repeat(count));
    System.out.printf("Día del mes: %d\n", diaMes);
    System.out.printf("Día de la semana: %s\n", diaSemana);
    System.out.printf("Día del año: %d\n", diaAnyo);
    System.out.printf("Nombre del mes: %s\n", nombreMes);
    System.out.printf("Número de mes: %d\n", numeroMes);
    System.out.printf("Año: %d\n", anyo);
    System.out.printf("Este mes tiene %s días"); // diaspormes
    System.out.printf("Este año tiene %s días"); // diasporaño
```

Comment: Responde [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37562/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-cu%C3%A1ntos-d%C3%ADas-tiene-el-mes-de-una-fecha-pasada-como-argumento-en-un)  tu pregunta?

Comment: Hola @Dramaturgo, sí, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) tiene dos métodos específicos para ello:

> #### [`lengthOfMonth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#lengthOfMonth())
>
> Devuelve la duración del mes representado por la fecha dada.
>
> Este método devuelve la duración del mes en días. Por ejemplo, una
> fecha en enero devolvería `31`.

---

> #### [`lengthOfYear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#lengthOfYear())
>
> Devuelve la duración del año representado por la fecha dada.
>
> Este método devuelve la duración del año en días, ya sea `365` ó
> `366`.

Probemos con febrero de `2024` que será bisiesto:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("2024-02-01", dtf);
int monthDays = ld.lengthOfMonth();
int yearDays  = ld.lengthOfYear();
int year = ld.getYear();
int month = ld.getMonthValue();
System.out.printf("Mes % 4d de %d tiene %d días%nAño %d tiene %d días",
                   month,year,monthDays,
                   year,yearDays);
```

**Salida:**

```
Mes    2 de 2024 tiene 29 días
Año 2024 tiene 366 días
```

---

Si cambias la fecha por `2022-02-01`, tendrás:

```
Mes    2 de 2022 tiene 28 días
Año 2022 tiene 365 días
```

Comment: Hola @A. Cedano, muchísimas gracias por responder, sí que me funcionó, gracias otra vez. :)

Comment: @kamehameha_21  me alegro de que te haya servido. [La nueva API Date Time de Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro) facilita tareas que antes eran hyper complicadas.